# Django FloatField not properly display: 54 instead of 5.4 (data store in Postgresql)

Tags: python, django, field

I've been looking for error for hours but could not find where is the problem

I have a 2 models (Sociodemographique and Clinique) each with a FloatField (dem_hglvaql and cli_tem respectively)
I have apply data-mask on each field that correctly works for data entry

When I inspect the field, value is '5.4' as in database but 54 is display

[image]

model.py

```
dem_hgl_val = models.FloatField("Si non, hémoglobine glyquée (%)", null=True, blank=True)

cli_tem = models.FloatField('Température', null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
self.fields['dem_hgl_val'] = forms.FloatField(label = 'Hémoglobine glyquée (%)',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '_ _._ _','data-mask':"00.00"}),required=False)

self.fields['cli_tem'] = forms.FloatField(label = 'Température',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '_ _ . _','data-mask':"00.0"}),required=False)
```

But when I display the Sociodemographique form, dem_hgl_val is not correctly displayed: 54 instead of 5.4

cli_tem field is correctly displayed

dem_hgl_val have validation form control and JS conditional behavior but even if I remove all these controls it doesn't seems to change anything

forms.py

```
    def clean_dem_hgl_val(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['dem_hgl_val']
        if data:
            if data > 100:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Vous ne pouvez pas saisir un pourcentage supérieur à 100%")
            if data < 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Vous ne pouvez pas saisir un pourcentage négatif")
        return data
```

JS script

```
// masque la section 3 'Co-morbidités' si la case 'section non applicable' est cochée
    $("#id_dem_com_nap").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            $("#id_dem_hgl_val").val(null);
});


// affichage conditionné section 'Diabete'
    $("#id_dem_dia").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $("#id_dem_hgl_val").val(null);
        }
        if ($(this).val() == 9) {
            $("#id_dem_hgl_val").val(null);
        }
        if ($(this).val().length<1) {
            $("#id_dem_hgl_val").val(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, so basically you type "5.4" in form, you see "5.4" in input value tag and in DB and it shows "54"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: data-mask':"0.00" instead of data-mask':"00.00"

```
self.fields['dem_hgl_val'] = forms.FloatField(label = 'Hémoglobine glyquée (%)',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '_ _._ _','data-mask':"00.00"}),required=False)
```